# How to allow containers on same host to communicate with each other?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am trying to get my containers to be able to communicate with each other. I have a cluster that runs 1 instance and a 2 containers on my task definition. I have set the hostname for each container when I created them. However, when I log into the containers, I cannot ping the other.

I have tried setting a link in a container to the other container and this does work for one way communication, however I cannot set a 2 way link for some reason, it complains I have a cycle.

I am using bridge mode with an ec2 instance.

Comment: Its better to use `awsvpc` mode, not `bridge` for that.

Comment: awsvpc does not allow hostname. "hostname is not supported on container when networkMode=awsvpc."